# How to get this type of output from following input using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following input Array which is dynamically generated.

```
let array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"]
```

This Array contain the Ids e.g "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b" and it related filter e.g "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat"

How I get the output like this

```
let outPut = [{"id":"5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b","filter":["Mon","Thu","Wed","Sat"]},{"id":"5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678","filter":["Tue","Thu","Sat"]}}
```

using lodash or javascript

Comment: Your output isn't valid. Is it supposed to be an array of two objects?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the out mistake. I need weekday in an array with related Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [lodash implicit chain sequences](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#lodash) of collection functions and the usage of each of the collection functions' shorthand [property()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#property) variations to transform this array into a properly grouped filter.

- Use [invokeMap()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invokeMap) to split each string in the array by a delimiter. In this case, we split it by `_`, resulting in an array of `['hash', 'day']`.
- Use [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter) to only get the items with a `day` suffix. We'll use the `property` shorthand variation of this collection function and evaluate the existence of `day` suffix which is under index 1.
- Use [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy), note the shorthand variation, to group each item with the `hash` prefix which is under index 0.
- Lastly, use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) to transform the grouped filter object into a grouped filter array by using the key (`hash`) of the group as the `id`. The resulting `filter` array is obtained by getting the `day` suffix of each of the grouped value which is under index 1 by using `map()`, shorthand function variation.

---

```
const result = _(array)
  .invokeMap('split', '_')
  .filter(1)
  .groupBy(0)
  .map((v, id) => ({ id, filter: _.map(v, 1) }))
  .value();
```

```js
const array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];

const result = _(array)
  .invokeMap('split', '_')
  .filter(1)
  .groupBy(0)
  .map((v, id) => ({ id, filter: _.map(v, 1) }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start coding using this code segment

```
var _ = require('lodash');

const array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];

const regualarData = _.filter(array, item => item.includes("_"));

const plainData = _.map(regualarData, item => {
    return {
      id: item.substring(0, item.indexOf("_")),
      day: item.substring(item.indexOf("_")+1),
    }; 
});

const nested = _.groupBy(plainData, 'id');

const response = [];
for (var key in nested) {
  if (nested.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    response.push({id: key , filter: _.map(nested[key],t => t.day)});
  }
}

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string using split, and store the filter days in an object. Then use that object to create the desired format.

```js
let array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];

//console.log( array );

// remove items with no underscore
array = array.filter( x => x.indexOf( '_' ) != -1 );

//console.log( array );

// create sortedData object
const sortedData = {};

array.forEach( function( x ) {
  const parts = x.split( '_' );
  const key = parts[0];
  const value = parts[1];
  
  if ( ! ( key in sortedData ) ) {
    sortedData[key] = [];
  }
  
  sortedData[key].push( value );
  
});

//console.log( sortedData );

const output = [];
for ( let key in sortedData ) {
    if ( sortedData.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
        output.push( { id: key, filters: sortedData[key] } );
    }
}

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use lodash, and want to take the functional approach, you need to:

- Split each item to a [id, filter] pair
- Filter out items that only have the id
- Group items by the id
- Format the objects

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, split, filter, groupBy, first, last, map  } = _;

const fn = flow(
  pr(map, item => split(item, '_')), // convert to [id, filter] pairs
  pr(filter, { length: 2 }), // filter out items without filter
  pr(groupBy, first), // group by the 1st item in each pair
  pr(map, (group, id) => ({ // format the objects
    id,
    filter: map(group, last) // get the filters from the pairs
  }))
)

const array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];

const result = fn(array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the terser lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, split, filter, groupBy, first, last, map  } = _;

const fn = flow(
  map(split('_')), // convert to [id, filter] pairs
  filter({ length: 2 }), // filters items without filter
  groupBy(first), // group by the 1st item in each pair
  map(group => ({ // format the objects
    id: first(first(group)), // take the id from the first item
    filter: map(last, group) // get the filters from the pairs
  }))
)

const array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];

const result = fn(array);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Kudos for the comments and not registering any new states!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"]
var tmpArr = [];
var tmpDay = [];
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var tmp = array[i].split("_");
    if(tmp.length == 1){
        tmpArr.push(array[i]);
        tmpDay.push([]);
    }
    else { 
        tmpDay[tmpArr.indexOf(tmp[0])].push(tmp[1]);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < tmpArr.length; i++){
    var tmpObj = {};
    tmpObj.id = tmpArr[i];
    tmpObj.filter = tmpDay[i];
    output.push(tmpObj);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much shorter version without loadash.

```js
var array = ["5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Tue", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Thu", "5c8faea05f60dd0c9447b678_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Sat", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Wed", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Thu", "5c8f653a247a4d513db2468b_Mon"];
array = array.map(v => v.split('_'));
var arr = {};
array.map(ar => {
 if(arr.hasOwnProperty(ar[0])){ 
  arr[ar[0]].push(ar[1]);
 }else{
  arr[ar[0]] = [];
 }
});
var _arr = [];
for(key in arr){
 _arr.push({id:key, filter:arr[key]});
}
console.log(_arr);
```